# Error "retrieve connection from pool timeout" when attempting to connect Node.js to MariaDB database hosted on Azure

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, mariadb

## Problem Statement

As the title suggests, I am trying to connect to a MariaDB database hosted on Azure with Node.js but I'm unable to identify the root cause of this error message.

```
% node dbTest.js                                        
Total connections:  0
Active connections:  0
Idle connections:  0
SqlError: (conn=-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10003ms
    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=5)
    at module.exports.createError (/Users/myuser/nextjs-test/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:64:10)
    at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (/Users/myuser/nextjs-test/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:349:26)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  sqlMessage: 'retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10003ms\n' +
    '    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=5)',
  sql: null,
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45028,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
```

## Minimum Reproducible Example

This is taken from the MariaDB docs.  I've only changed the credentials in the initialization pool and changed the SQL query from something that would be invalid in most DB schemas to something that is valid.

```
// Required Modules
const mariadb = require("mariadb");

//Initialize Pool
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
   host: "<host name or IPv4 address>",
   user: "<user name>",
   password: "<password>",
   database: "<database name>",
   connectionLimit: 100,
});

console.log("Total connections: ", pool.totalConnections());
console.log("Active connections: ", pool.activeConnections());
console.log("Idle connections: ", pool.idleConnections());

async function main() {
   let conn;

   try {
      conn = await fetchConn();

      // Use Connection
      var rows = await get_select(conn);
      for (i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
         console.log("Total connections: ", pool.totalConnections());
         console.log("Active connections: ", pool.activeConnections());
         console.log("Idle connections: ", pool.idleConnections());

         console.log(rows);
      }
   } catch (err) {
      // Manage Errors
      console.log(err);
   } finally {
      // Close Connection
      if (conn) conn.end();
   }
}

// Fetch Connection
async function fetchConn() {
   let conn = await pool.getConnection();
   console.log("Total connections: ", pool.totalConnections());
   console.log("Active connections: ", pool.activeConnections());
   console.log("Idle connections: ", pool.idleConnections());
   return conn;
}

//Get select query
async function get_select(conn) {
   return await conn.query("SELECT 1 AS val");
}
main();
```

## Probably not the root cause

I don't think it's a network or firewall issue because I have whitelisted my IP address and I am able to connect to the targeted database from the same machine with `mysql.connector` in Python as well as with IDE's like SQL Developer and MySQL Workbench.

I don't think it is a DB configuration issue because I've checked the DB timeout settings.  If there is a timeout as the error message suggests, it is probably originating from my local machine, not the DB.

I don't think it is an IPv4 versus IPv6 issue because I've tried substituting the host name with the IPv4 IP address.  Furthermore, a lot of the suggested solutions on StackOverflow in this vein are addressing the specific case where `localhost` was being used as the host, which is not my use case.

I've confirmed that there are no typos in the database credentials.  And for troubleshooting purposes, I included the database credentials explicitly to ensure that the issue was not related to issues fetching environmental variables.

I've confirmed the database uses the default port 3306.

## Additional Info

Other OP's on StackOverflow have faced the same error, but the answers on their posts are not resolving the issue for me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075439/why-am-i-getting-a-timeout-error-when-exporting-a-mariadb-connection-pool-in-nod), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530520/nodejs-connector-to-mariadb-keeps-timeouting), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76378341/nodejs-not-able-to-connect-to-maria-db-able-to-connect-through-command-line), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593854/i-cant-connect-my-nodejs-server-to-my-mariadb-raspberry-pi), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70118401/unable-to-make-request-to-my-mariadb-database-using-node-server), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76556062/connecting-express-server-and-mariadb)

Most of the above StackOverflow links have MRE's that I've reproduced, but even after applying the accepted answer from those posts I get the same error in many cases (I think all cases, but I've lost track).

## System and Package Details

macOS Sonoma 14.1
node v20.10.0
mariadb@3.2.2

Comment: I think you doing like this [example](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/)

Comment: the above reference is working with local MySQL [reference](https://github.com/mariadb-developers/nodejs-quickstart/tree/main)

Comment: facing the same error  using `mariadb` to connect to Azure MariaDB server  but connecting to local MySQL and able to connect to the MariaDB server with Package `mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I followed the reference  [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/database-developer-guide?tabs=MySQL%2Cazure-cli#mariadb-and-mysql-on-azure)  from the  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/database-developer-guide?tabs=MariaDB%2Cazure-cli#use-sdk-packages-to-develop-your-mariadb-on-azure)  and got the same error.
- For Azure identity with  `@azure/arm-mariadb`, I followed this  [DOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-mariadb).

Note:

> Azure Database for MariaDB  [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/overview)  on the retirement path. We strongly recommend that you migrate to Azure Database for MySQL. For more information about migrating to Azure Database for MySQL, see What's happening to Azure Database for  [MariaDB](https://aka.ms/WhatsHappeningToMariaDB)?

- In Azure, we use the  [connection string](https://i.imgur.com/IpsuLIj.png)  in the  `var conn = mysql.createConnection`.
- The code works with local MySQL, and for Azure, there is a difference in the format of the connection string.

**In local mysql:**

```js
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

const pool = mariadb.createPool({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Password',
  connectionLimit: 5,
  database: 'databaseName', // Add this line to specify the database
});

async function selectAndInsert() {
  let conn;
  try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();

    // SELECT query
    const selectResult = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM example_table');
    console.log('SELECT Result:', selectResult);

    // INSERT query
    const insertResult = await conn.query('INSERT INTO example_table (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)', ['New Person', 28]);
    console.log('INSERT Result:', insertResult);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    if (conn) return conn.end();
  }
}

// Call the function
selectAndInsert();
```

[image]

[image]

**Code with the MySQL package to connect to Azure Database for MariaDB server:**

The code below connects to a database, performs a SELECT query on the  `example_table`.

```java
const fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Replace these values with your actual database credentials
const dbConfig = {
  host: "Server name",
  user: "Server admin login name",
  password: "your_actual_password",
  database: "your_actual_database",
  port: 3306,
  ssl: { required: true }
};

// Create a connection to the database
const conn = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);

// Connect to the database
conn.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to database:', err.message);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to the database');
  
  // Perform a SELECT query
  conn.query('SELECT * FROM example_table', (queryErr, results) => {
    if (queryErr) {
      console.error('Error executing SELECT query:', queryErr.message);
      return;
    }
    
    // Process the query results
    console.log('Query results:', results);

    // Close the database connection
    conn.end((endErr) => {
      if (endErr) {
        console.error('Error closing database connection:', endErr.message);
      } else {
        console.log('Database connection closed');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Local:**
[image]
**Azure:**

[image]

Comment: A thousand thanks, @Sampath!  The key insight from your post is to use the mysql connector, not the mariadb connector, to connect to the mariadb database with Node.js.  Very counterintuitive.  I'm so thankful for your help!